# MUI auto import suggestions not working in VS Code, Next.js 13 project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, material-ui

I'm working on a `Next.js 13` project with `MUI` installed and VS Code doesn't offer auto imports from the `@mui/material` library. This is shown in the screenshot.

[image]

Auto imports from other libraries work in this folder. In other projects that are not based on `Next js 13`, auto imports from `MUI` also work.
Please tell me how can I fix this?

Here is my **tsconfig.json** if it may help:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Thanks for attention!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's looking normal. But sometimes need again run VSCode typescript engine when after add new packages.

1. `shift+cmd+p`
2. Select Typescript Reload

Note : You have to sure you are at correct folder path on VSCode. If you started wrong project path on VSCode you can't see your project packages with auto imports.

Also this problem isn't relational with only MUI, maybe [this document](https://dev.to/shanesc/how-to-get-javascript-auto-import-suggestions-working-in-vs-code-aig) could help you.

Answer (score 0):

i remove 'JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly' extension.
it works.